# Looking for a better algorithm for finding the slope of an input signal

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, algorithms, octave, approximation

I've got an input signal that while sloping up, approximately bounces off an imaginary line.  I'm looking for the equation to that imaginary line.  I have a method, but is very brute force and it takes too long.  I'm looking for ways to optimize my approach or hopefully learn about a completely different more efficient method.
I've written a script in Octave that will do what I want, but it takes 3-10 seconds (with an input signal of 1800 samples) depending on how many iterations I run.

My brute force algorithm in Octave:

```
  x = 0:1:1800;
  for i = 1:200
    p = polyfit(x, input, 1);  % p gives the slope and offset
    output= polyval(p, x);
    input = clip(input, output);
  endfor
```

the clip function clamps the input to the output.  Clamps the input signal to the linear approximation.

```
  for i = 1:length(input)
    if(input(i) > output(i))
      input(i) = output(i);
    end
  endfor
```

To better explain what I'm looking for, I've included the rough image below.  Of course, the red signal is the input and I'm looking for the equation of the blue line.

[image: Signal example]

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand what your'e asking correctly

To get the minimum slope of the image I would run an calculate the slope at each point (should be fast enough) and than take the minimal one.

For example :

```
x = 1:.05:3000;
y = 100+x + 300*sin(2*pi*x/1000);
origin = [0 0] ; % or origin = [ x(1) y(1) ];
slope = (y - origin(2)) ./ (x - origin(1));
[ minslope , minidx ] = min( slope ) ;
angle = atand( minslope );
figure;plot( x,y ,'-');
hold on;
plot([ origin(1) x(minidx)] , [origin(2) y(minidx)] ,'-r');
```

Will give you this slope:
[image]

Best of luck!,

Elad